# Stuck in low graphics mode - need to re-enable Intel card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

After installing NVIDIA 331 graphics driver for my NVIDIA 740M my laptop boots to Ubuntu in "low graphics mode". If someone could walk me through the steps of deactivating the NVIDIA driver and re-enabling the Intel one that would help me out quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have 770M and had same problem with 14.04 Ubuntu. If I were you, I'd:

1. Uninstall everything related to nvidia and bumblebee

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove nvidia-* 
   sudo apt-get remove bumblebee-*
   ```
2. Install nvidia-331-updates
3. install bumblebee

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
   ```
4. configure `bumblebee.conf`

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
   ```

   as suggested by [the Ubuntu wiki bumblebee page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee). It should contain:

   ```
   Driver=nvidia

   KernelDriver=nvidia-331-updates
   LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates
   XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
   ```
5. Reboot

It's not perfect, but better than Intel, for sure.